# Why is my "runtime loaded image" in poor quality and with shifted pixels?

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game on Unity that works with images: the user should be able to load an entire folder of images and play with them in the game.

The only working way I found is to load all my images in the Streaming Assets folder and then get a byte array of the image to pass to a Texture2D and use that to create a sprite

```
void loadSprite(string path)
{

    byte[] imgData;
    imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    tex.LoadImage(imgData);

    Vector2 pivot = new Vector2(tex.width / 2, tex.height / 2);
    Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, tex.width, tex.height), pivot, 100.0f);

    image.sprite = sprite;

}
```

I then assign the newly created image to an existing 100px x 100px UI Image as a sprite.

This is where it becomes messy:

The loaded image
https://puu.sh/DJefk/c8549aa269.png

The output I get
https://puu.sh/DJ3IZ/c746985374.png

Comment: I'm no expert in unity, but don't you set the textures extents to 1 by 1 pixels in the constructor?

Comment: yes, I found that function around and the issue is still there even if I pass a proper resolution (1024x1024)

Comment: Your game scale is 3.something . Can it be the reason you see the image as low resolution?